# reference date in cell for file name in vlookup

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I have a vlookup that references the prior month end file on a shared drive.  These files are saved with the date in the file name as mmddyyyy.

```
=VLOOKUP([@[DealerCode]],'\\mypath\[Performance_07312017.xlsm]SheetName'!$B:$K,10,FALSE)
```

The formula must be manually changed at the beginning of each month.  I want to have the formula look up from the previous months file by referencing the current date in C1.  I've tried the following, but I get #VALUE.

```
=VLOOKUP([@[Dealer Code]],CONCATENATE("'\\mypath\[Performance_",TEXT(EOMONTH($C$1,-1),"mmddyyyy"),".xlsm]SheetName'!$B:$K"),10,FALSE)
```

I want to leave the month end files closed, so I don't think INDIRECT is an option.

It seems like this should be simple, but I'm stumped.  Thanks in advance for any guidance y'all can give.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution short of VBA is with Indirect, but as you already mentioned, it does not work with closed files. There is a free add-in called [Morefunc.dll](http://ccm.net/download/download-24205-morefunc-macro-add-in-for-excel), which has a function called IndirectEXT, which works with closed workbooks.